# Setting PHP's default timezone

Tags: php, time, timezone

In my web app, I let the users choose their preferred timezone from a list (that contains [all timezones that PHP supports](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)).

Let's say that `$_POST['timezone']` is the chosen timezone (*e.g.* `America/New_York`).
I set it with the following code which produces no errors:

```
default_date_timezone_set($_POST['timezone']);
```

But when I reload the page it goes back to what it was before (*e.g.* `Europe/Moscow`).
Do I have to set the default timezone in every script or isn't the function (`default_date_timezone_set`) working properly?
Thanks!

Comment: PHP is stateless, this means that for every request you lose any setting or variable.

Comment: Doesn't that function set it at the server level? Wouldn't you want it on the session or client level since it is based on the user?

Comment: I think you do. As with any function that changes core setting, those changes have script runtime scope. Otherwise, "many users" concept would not be possible...

Comment: @JimmyBanks, no, I understand session and cookies pretty good. And what do SQL tables have to do with anything? I just forgot that `default_date_timezone_set` doesn't affect the server but the user's session

Comment: A blank POST statement like that, doesnt effect anythign but the one page, you need to store the variable settings somewhere (again, SQL Table, session, cookie) and call it on every page the user browses to.  Dont mean to offend but this is very basic php programming and you clearly dont understand it. And no it doesnt effect the users session unless you store it in their session variables. And even then, once their session is over, they will need to reset their timezone every time they return which isnt very intuitive. Storing it in a table is the best bet, and calling it when they sign in.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Don't you think I know how to save a value into a session? I already said that I forgot that that function affected the user session and not the server. (It affects only how clients see dates and not how the dates are stored in the database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function changes the timezone for the execution of the script only. 
You could store the timezone in a session variable and set the time zone on top of every page.

Answer (score 1):

You should save it in the database and set the timezone any time you do anything time related.  It's working properly.  It's only supposed to set it for that script execution (one HTTP request).

Answer (score 1):

Set a cookie that contains the timezone the user chooses.

```
/// Make sure you sanitize all POST/COOKIE variables if needed.
$timezone = $_COOKIE['timezone'];

if(isset($_POST['timezone'])) {
    /// Set cookie for some amount of time -- I chose 2 weeks
    setcookie('timezone',$_POST['timezone'],time()+60*60*24*14);
    $timezone = $_POST['timezone'];
}

default_date_timezone_set($timezone);
```